# Constellation of BPSK doesn't look as expected

Tags: sdr, bpsk, gnuradio

I'm a total novice when it comes to RF beyond basic concepts.

I'm trying to use a HackRF One to pull the data coming off of [this](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/NXYTR2/4573123) transponder, which theoretically transmits data on a 3.59MHz carrier.

I've followed some tutorials on BPSK demodulation, but while I expect the constellation to look like this:

[image: Ideal BPSK constellation]

I'm getting points all over the I and Q axis with no consistency whenever it transmits (having trouble getting a screenshot of just when the device is transmitting). Here's my current setup - is there a parameter I have incorrect or am missing?

[image: GNU Radio]

Comment: I don't think the hackrf supports an extremely low sampling rate like that. If you used a normal sampling rate like e.g. 8 MHz and look at the received spectrum (qt frequency sink), do you see your transmission?

Comment: Is it dots randomly everywhere, dots populating a disk, or dots on (or roughly on) a circle?  Maybe give us a hand sketch if you can't take a screenshot.